# How to render page content with custom blocks when using get_the_content()?

Tags: php, wordpress

So we have a custom page template in our Wordpress theme, that fetches 3 different pages' content and renders them into a tabbed layout. It includes the glossary section like so:

```php
<div class="glossary-content content e8-tab-panel" data-tab="glossary">
    <?php
    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content( null, false, 80 ) );
    echo ($content);
    ?>
</div>
```

When we use a block (like Kadence Blocks TOC) or another Table of Contents plugin, the TOC is not rendered.

If I modify the above and get rid of the apply_filters call, then the code for the TOC shows up as a comment.

```html
<div class="glossary-content content e8-tab-panel" data-tab="glossary">
    <?php
    $content = get_the_content( null, false, 80 );
    echo ($content);
    ?>
</div>
```

Gives me this in the content output:

```html
<!-- wp:kadence/tableofcontents {"uniqueID": ...
```

Keeping the `apply_filters` call in there, strips the block info comments out.

Is there a filter I need to call in order to get this page to render custom blocks? Specifically the Kadence Blocks TOC, but really I'll use any TOC plugin at this point. I have a feeling that I am missing a step that will parse the content through all the filters registered by installed plugins, but my search has come up empty.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Went down a deep rabbit hole trying to figure out how to trigger the rendering of blocks. Turns out that WP relies heavily on a super global array and it must contain the Page to be rendered. But by default it is set to my containing page which is using this custom template (not my 3 loaded page fragments).

So I set it manually for each of the 3 sections before fetching and filtering the content.

```html
<div class="glossary-content content e8-tab-panel" data-tab="glossary">
    <?php
        $GLOBALS['post'] = WP_Post::get_instance( 80 ); // Override to ensure block parsing.
        $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content( null, false, 80 ) );
        echo $content;
    ?>
</div>
```

Interestingly you must set a **post** global value with an instance of **WP_Post** even though this is a **Page**.

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided to me on Mastodon. Credit to **@gmazzap@phpc.social**.

A more "canonical" way of doing that is:

```php
function my_render_post_content(int $id): void {
    $GLOBALS['post'] = get_post($id);
    the_content();
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

This ensures full compatibility with plugins listening for different hooks and ensures you don't have issues accessing data from the "wrapper" page later.